# What is the significance of Panchastavi hymn?

Tags: shaktism, kashmiri-shaivism, lalita, hymn

Pancha-stavi is a beautiful hymn in praise of goddess tripura. It is important in kashmir school of shaivism.

It contains in it many esoteric meanings. Lakshmidhara in his commentary of Saundarya Lahiri also has mentioned about it.

What is its significance ?
What are the commentaries available (if any)?